# Is there a reason this function would or should eventually crash a web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I've got a react application and I want to display the time and date with the time updating every minute as it should. I wrote this code but if I leave the app running for an extended period of time I eventually get a crash that tells me the memory has been exceeded.

If there is a better way to do this I'd love some guidance. Thanks.

```
let currentDate = new Date();    

  setInterval(() => {
    currentDate = new Date();
    setDate({
      time: currentDate.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      }),
      date: currentDate.toDateString().slice(3),
    });
  }, 60000);
```

Comment: Yes, basically if your memory doesn't gets garbage collected for some reason (probably due to still being used somehow), it will exceed the memory from your browser. Your solution should focus on which part of your software is holding this data. What does setDate do there?

Comment: What performance auditing have you done to track what is using memory and what/when the crash occurs? I can't tell from this limited snippet, but where/how are you starting the interval? Starting more than 1? Can you share more complete code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexanderSantos `setDate` is very likely a state updater function in React for a `date` state variable, based on function component state naming convention.

Comment: You should run the setInterval in a useEffect hook and clear it if you leave the component. Otherwise it will run forever. So sth. like this:

useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const currentDate = new Date()
      setDate({
        ...{
          time: currentDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            second: '2-digit',
          }),
          date: currentDate.toDateString().slice(3),
        },
      })
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

Comment: The global *currentDate* seems entirely redundant.

Comment: @DrewReese sure! I think i expressed myself poorly. It's hard to tell it's behavior without the code, the problem may be in the way he sets this state inside the function, or may be not. Maybe it's from a lib, maybe not... We need some more details to know it.